# Issue with jenkins X promotion

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-x

I have some basic Jenkins X cluster on Kubernetes on GCP. It works all fine. I can deploy in staging (jx import) and it updates with automated webhooks etc.

But now I want to promote an app to production:

```
jx promote --env production --version 0.0.3 myapp
Promoting app myapp version 0.0.3 to namespace jx-production
pipeline user/myapp/master
Using pipeline: user/myapp/master build: #3
```

It seems okay but nothing happens? What am I missing? There is no app in my jx-production namespace.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is any better:

```
jx promote --env production --version 0.0.3 --app myapp
```

more help in the [online CLI reference](https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx/) for the command: [jx promote](https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_promote/)

has `myapp` ever been promoted to `production` before & do you have a production environment setup? Check via

```
jx get env
```